# 'LIKE' function for Lists

Tags: python

Is there any equivalent `'LIKE'` function(like in MySQL) for lists. for example;

This is my list:

```
abc = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'twenty one']
```

if I give the word `"on"`, it should print the matching words from the list (in this case: `'one'`, `'twenty one'`) and if I give `"fo"`, it should print `False`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
[m for m in abc if 'on' in m]
```

This roughly translates to "for each element in abc, append element to a list if the element contains the substring 'on'"

Comment: This will also return an empty list if nothing is found -- empty lists are false.

Comment: @Blackmoon I felt that the empty list comment was important as it does address a piece of the question. I wasn't trying to split hairs.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> abc = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'twenty one']
>>> print [word for word in abc if 'on' in word]
['one', 'twenty one']
```

Answer (score 3):

Would these [`list comprehensions`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) suffice?

```
>>> abc = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'twenty one']
>>> [i for i in abc if 'on' in i]
['one', 'twenty one']
>>> [i for i in abc if 'fo' in i]
[]
```

You could wrap this in a function:

```
>>> def like(l, word):
...     words = [i for i in abc if word in i]
...     if words:
...         print '\n'.join(words)
...     else:
...         print False
...
>>> like(abc, 'on')
one
twenty one
>>> like(abc, 'fo')
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in abc:
    if "on" in x:
        print x
```

Or, as a function,

```
def like(str, search):
    res = []
    for x in search:
       if str in x:
           res.append(x)
    return res
```

Comment: List comprehensions are the way to go

Comment: Another -1 for the function solution

Comment: List comprehensions are certainly more Pythonic and `str` hides the built-in class `str`.